# How can I tell which items Amazon dropped from my orders?

Tags: amazon

I am ordering food on Amazon/Whole Foods.  Delivery slots are very hard to get here/now.  You must "attempt to check out" several times a day. If you are very lucky, a slot will be available and it will place the order.

*After* the order is placed, Amazon does a good job of tracking which items were canceled.  Which is fine.

The problem is, items sit in my shopping cart for a week waiting for a delivery slot. **In the meantime, Amazon will *silently* remove the item from my shopping cart**.  There is no notice of this (as there is for other Amazon carts e.g. regular or Pantry). This seems to happen when *Whole Foods* goes out of stock for an item.  *However, when the item comes back in stock, it does not reappear in my shopping cart*.

My meat-glacier brain cannot keep up with these arbitrary drops.  To have to manually re-sync the whole order against an independent list, *3-6 times a day for a week*, is just too much.  (it is impracticable to discover a delivery slot is available, then review/improve the order; by the time you get back, the slot will be *long gone*).

My question is - *germane to the Whole Foods section* of an Amazon cart - **Is there a way to see a history of what the system has dropped from the order?**  How do I figure out what they have silently removed?

Methods, hacks, tools or apps to help with this problem will also be welcome (presuming they "play nice" with the Whole Foods cart and don't only work on main Amazon).

Also highly welcome is a way to edit a Whole Foods order after it has been placed (but before pick/delivery).

<sup>as a note, Amazon Pantry has a similar problem with churn causing cart drops (my 22-slot Pantry cart has melted to 9 items in 3 days). However Pantry will give you a one-time interstitial the next time you visit your Amazon cart.</sup>